# User's field autocomplete/autosuggest widget

Tags: views, entities

I have a user field where multiple users can be added. Currently, I am using the auto-complete widget.

Is there a module that allows you to customize what can be additionally shown on autocomplete? I would imagine that you could add an 'autocomplete' view similar to full-page or teaser. 
Something like Facebook's search. Providing more info like picture or residence of the user.

Comment: Might be possible using [Finder](https://drupal.org/project/finder) (or some of it's code at least), but it would be to long to post entire manual here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your field setting, you can choose a view for node or user references:
[image]

To create this kind of view-reference, you have to previously create a view with a reference page like this :

[image]

Note that every field you'll choose for the view, will appear in the autocomplete input

Hope this can help

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: Hope this solve your pb

Comment: Where can you find the first page? /admin/structure/types/manage/my_content_type/fields/field_genre/field-settings ?

Comment: Your field must be a 'User Reference' or a 'Node Reference' type. Then : /admin/structure/types/manage/my_content_type/fields/field_name_user_reference (and then a collapsed fieldset "VIEWS - NODES THAT CAN BE REFERENCED" at the bottom of the page)